# Problem when animating with IK blender 4.0

Tags: animation, rigify, inverse-kinematics

Well, I'm a beginner, and I was watching a tutorial on the basics of Blender. Right now, I'm stuck here.

[image]

I got the IK, but the problem is when I try to animate it, for example, crouch, legs open to the sides, I tried to block the directions, but for example, if I block z and y, it goes to one side etc., what I want to do is that When I bend over, my legs are "straight" and don't go sideways.

[image]

[image]

This is what happens when I try to block addresses

Comment: Hello, it looks like you haven't created pole target bones? They are made for this purpose, they allow to point the knees toward the desired direction...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't created a pole target bone for your knee. They are made for this purpose, they allow to point the knees toward the desired direction:

[image]

In *Edit* mode create a bone in front of your knee (parent it to the root bone, deactivate its *Deform* option):

[image]

In *Pose* mode, select the IK bone and in the IK constraint select its pole target bone, you may need to change the *Pole Angle* value if you see that the IK bone is undesirably rotated in rest pose:

[image]

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your help, I had a question looking at your character, is it advisable to use that root bone? For what purpose do you use it? In my character, I don't have that root bone that unites the entire body.

Comment: Yes use it, it is supposed to be the parent of all the controller bones, poletarget bones, and bottom spine bone, useful when you need to do a walk cycles for example